# Docker build fails when project reference and nuget feed added

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to create docker image/container in my local machine. It is working fine if I've a simple project without any project reference and private nuget feed. I'm getting the below errors when I do docker build (from src\Account\Account.host folder) after adding a project reference and private nuget feed.

- Skipping project "/Shared/SharedComponent/SharedComponent.csproj" because it was not found.
- error NU1101: Unable to find package . No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

I tried to modify it but getting copying files out of context errors. My questions are:
- is it possible to run docker build with the below folder structure?
- do i need to use docker compose if i want to stick with the same folder structure?
- I've got other project where i need to add another docker file but I'm just testing with one project which doesnt seems to be working.

**Project folder structure**

- Shared

  ++ SharedComponent

  ```
    +++ ShareComponent.csproj

    +++ Other files
  ```
- Account

  ++Account.Host

  ```
    +++ Account.Host.csproj (SharedComponent.csproj reference added)

    +++ Dockerfile

    +++ Other files
  ```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Account.Host.csproj", "./"]

RUN dotnet restore "./Account.Host.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "Account.Host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Account.Host.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Account.Host.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker build needs to be able to see the whole project when it builds, so it can determine if any of the files have changed (among other things).

You probably need to run `docker build` from the root directory of the project, and tell it where the `Dockerfile` is, like this:

```sh
docker build -t the_name_of_the_image -f Account/Account.Host/Dockerfile
```

The above might not be quite right, but the directory structure you posted didn't render right :(

Comment: Thanks @OlympusMonds. I think you meant "docker build -t the_name_of_the_image -f Account/Account.Host/Dockerfile ." when i run from the root folder, it is failing on "COPY ["Account.Host.csproj", "./"]" and throwing "stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder087905431/Account.Host.csproj: no such file or directory". And when I change the dockerfile to "COPY ["Account/Account.Host/Account.Host.csproj", "./"]", it is failing with the same original error on dotnet restore line. i.e. Skipping project "/Shared/SharedComponent/SharedComponent.csproj" it was not found and Unable to find package.